# MYSQL optimize for a lot of GET_LOCK and high number of connections (Codeigniter Sessions)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use Codeigniter 3 with database-backed sessions. It uses `SELECT GET_LOCK("$SESSION_ID", 300)` to prevent concurrent requests causing issue with session data.

This works fine until I have a ton of traffic causing a bunch of open connections all calling this function and waiting for the lock to be released

It sometimes brings the application to a halt for a couple of minutes. It never reaches my max number of connections in mysql and CPU and RAM usages are fine, but performance is slow for all users of that database server. (Not sure why it doesn't perform ok). I do use pt-kill to remove any queries taking longer than 15 seconds.

I already tried using the redis driver that had its own performance issues so I am back to the database sessions.

So my questions are:

How do I optimize my application to perform well when I get a ton of traffic and cases GET_LOCK queries to pile up and open connections to mysql. I was thinking I could use persistent connection; but not sure if that is a good idea as most people never recommend this

Comment: Are you literally using the string 'SESSION_ID' or do you mean you have a distinct lock name for each session?

Comment: It is distinct per session id

Comment: Can you confirm the processes are waiting for that lock? If you use SHOW PROCESSLIST, they'll display with "User lock" in the State column.

Comment: I really don't like to use `pt-kill` (or any other query-killer) for normal day to day application usage. Killing queries is for emergencies. I'm willing to assert that using a query-killer under normal application conditions is an antipattern.

Comment: Pretty sure it was a user lock. New relic was reporting a bunch of get lock queries taking 15 seconds. Pt-kill removes queries after 15 seconds

Comment: The general answer is: Make sure after your app acquires a lock, that it does minimal work, and releases the lock as promptly as possible. Don't put any code in between the get and the release that might run in unbounded time. For example, I see a lot of developers call out to web service APIs while their code is holding a lock. Then the day the web service they are calling is unresponsive, the app causes a logjam because all those sessions are holding locks while they wait for the API calls to time out.

Comment: You haven't described anything about what your app is doing between the get and the release of a lock, so I'm not sure how to give any specific advice about how to optimize it. You mentioned persistent connections but I doubt that would fix this case.

Comment: As far as I understand the way the lock works in codeigntier is that it locks when page loads and unlocks when done. So whatever happens in between will only allow 1 process at a time per session. The problem happens when a process take a bit and the user makes many requests at once the then there are a bunch of processes in the GET_LOCK section.

Comment: LOL - if you want the get_lock() to time out after 15 seconds, why do you use `GET_LOCK(<name>, 300)`? You know the second argument is the timeout in seconds, right?

Comment: This is provided by the codeigniter framework and I try not to modify their code.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I haven't used CodeIgniter, but are you saying this is _default_ behavior of the framework to do this locking? What a bad idea. Okay, I guess the advice is, "optimize everything your app does." Sorry I can't be more specific, but I have no idea what your app code is doing, and apparently if  any request takes a long time, it will cause a backup. That is criminally bad application architecture.

Comment: This is what the framework does...is there any my.ini/cnf change I can make to deal with high number of these queries running? I can try to optimize application but the reality is this type of scenario happens from time to time

Comment: There is no need to add to the excellent comments from @BillKarwin; but on another note, I'm tucking this question away on my list of reasons to *not* use CodeIgniter.

Comment: No, your framework is requesting a lock... MySQL grants the lock... other connections that request the same lock must wait until that lock is released. There's no MySQL config change that affects that workflow.

Comment: I don't mean change the behavior of how the lock works; but changing mysql  settings so it doesn't get slow when a lot of these requests are being made. I have many customers on one server and when this happens other users are affected.

Comment: I understand what you mean. There is no MySQL configuration that helps.

Comment: What about thead_cache_size? https://serverfault.com/a/729353/71770.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.